# Fastest Algorithm/Software for MST and Searching on Large Sparse Graphs

Tags: python, algorithm, search, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

I've developed a graph clustering model for assigning destinations to vehicle routes, but my implementation is very slow. It takes about two days to process a graph with 400k nodes.

My current implementation in Python is as follows:

```
Input data is a sparse graph:
       Edges are roads
       Nodes are vehicle destinations and road intersections

Create Minimum Spanning Tree using Prims Algorithm

For every edge in the MST:
      Perform depth-first-search on the the two subgraphs on each side of the edge:
              Sum up road lengths for each edge
      If total road length for one of the subgraphs is within a defined range, then remove the edge
```

Any recommendations to make this implementation faster? Could using Networkx or Neo4J speed this up?

Comment: Suspect there might be a fast implementation based on dynamic trees, but would be surprised if it were built in to a convenient library.

Comment: I have added some performance test results to my answer.  MST performance depends on many things, not just the node count.  I have included varying edge : vertex ratios.  How do your results compare?

Comment: @ravenspoint The MST shouldn't ever be the bottleneck here if I understand the algorithm correctly.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat The question has too little details to know for sure.  In general DFS goes very fast, however the MST runs once but a DFS on half the graph runs twice for every edge!  The does not change the answer, however, using a C++ library implementation of DFS will be many times faster than hand coded python.  It would be helpful to know what the metric is, along with many other details missing from the question.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of information initially, it's been a while since I've posted in stack overflow. I've added some more detail to my original question if that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late update, but solution ultimately involved using Kruskal's algorithm instead of Primm's algorithm.

Rewriting my existing process in C++ dropped processing speed from 2 days to 10 hours.

Using Kruskals algorithm in Python dropped processing speed from 2 days to 1 hour.

Answer (score 1):

> Could using Networkx or Neo4J speed this up?

Yes.  These libraries are written in C++ which is many times faster than python (the usual quote is approx 50 times faster )

Personally, I would recommend moving to C++ entirely.  Python is fine for toy applications, but large graphs need the performance of a compiled language.

Here is the c++ code I use to find minimum spanning trees

https://github.com/JamesBremner/PathFinder/blob/50b89a0ff57e13cb34b0348b073d698a22ede406/src/GraphTheory.cpp#L180-L251

Here are some timing tests on randomly generated graphs

| Vertex Count | Run time seconds 1 edge/vertex | Run time seconds 3 edges/vertex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1,000 | 0.1 | 0.1 |
| 10,000 | 4 | 17 |
| 100,000 | 410 | 1900 |

Comment: Your question was "Could using Networkx or Neo4J speed this up?"  My answer was "yes".  This is still the correct answer.  That you have found that using one algorithm rather than the original one you used is even faster does not make this answer wrong.